# Chat oneboxing is broken for feeds from Medium

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, onebox

Worldbuilding has a [blog hosted on Medium](https://medium.com/universe-factory), and we have a [chat feed](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/27736/universe-factory?tab=feeds) for new posts.  It [used to onebox those posts](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/27736?m=30757663#30757663), but 6-8 weeks ago that broke and we now get [text posts with no links](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32769095#32769095), which makes it harder for our users to go to the new posts.

I at first thought this might be a problem at Medium's end, but I also syndicate that feed to Dreamwidth, where posts [show up with no problems](http://universe-factory-feed.dreamwidth.org/profile).  So I think it's something about oneboxing, not something about the feed.  I'm not aware of other chat feeds from Medium to test with.  Oneboxing from other sources continues to work as far as I've seen.

Comment: Yeah, you can see it breaking [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-449/universe-factory?tab=recent) - up until July 1 it was oneboxed, then next time in Aug 5 it's not oneboxed. Sure nothing changed on the blog side though?

Comment: @ShadowWizard nothing under our control changed on the blog side AFAIK.  It's always possible that something changed in the Medium platform, but the Dreamwidth RSS feed continues to work.

Comment: Well, I see there is a redirection, e.g. https://medium.com/universe-factory/building-the-world-of-pangaea-d3015cd8485b?source=rss----6b76dbf2e0eb---4 becomes https://medium.com/universe-factory/building-the-world-of-pangaea-d3015cd8485b#.p74dxwmot - since SE probably scraping the page, maybe they miss the redirection?

Comment: Medium oneboxes? This is the first I've heard of it...

Comment: @hichris123 it did when we started the blog (over a year ago), yes.  Lately, not so much.

Comment: You must've just been lucky... http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/search?room=89&q=medium.com shows no oneboxes and I can't find a reference to Medium oneboxes on Meta.

Comment: @ShadowWizard We're not scraping the page. It's an RSS feed.

Comment: @hichris123 There is no onebox configured for Medium specifically, but any site that provides an RSS feed of posts can theoretically be set up as a feed in chat... and that oneboxes in a fairly generic way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This oneboxing makes use of our generic "RSS Feed" onebox, which is generally fine, except that for some reason recently the posts from Medium started getting parsed out on our end as having no summary and no content, which in turn broke the rendering code.

Best guess is that the feed changed to use `<content:encoded>` instead of `<content>`, so the way we used to parse it out was no longer picking up the text correctly.

Got a fix out in prod now, so any future feed posts should onebox as they used to.